# Spring MVC REST: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException was thrown

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-3

I want to use Spring 3.0 MVC to develop REST...I test a very simple code ,but org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException was  thrown here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class RestTest {


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/1", 
            headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Employee getEmp(@PathVariable String id) {
    Employee e = new Employee("helloWorld","stip of world");
    return e;
    }


}
```

beans-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
   <property name="messageConverters">
       <list>
           <ref bean="jsonConverter" />

       </list>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" 
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.stip.rest"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

the exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jsonConverter' while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonConverter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.isFullyTyped()Z

jackson-core.jar and jackson-mapper have been added to the build path...
i try my best to fix..but..Can you help me ...Thanks

Comment: which version of jackson are you using?Did you check its compatibility with Spring 3?

Comment: @AravindA 1.90..i didn't check compatibility...which version is prefer?

Comment: Please add the version of the libraries you are using. You should just add the right jackson libraries to the classpath and it should work. Check the spring pom to get the version used by spring.

Answer (score 0):

Yo dont need   register   converter  if you add  jackson library to your classpath spring will return  json  to client for each @ResponseBody  annotated controller metod.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check if:

```
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
```

are listed in the schemas at the top of your applicationContext-web.xml in the schemaLocation tag.